# Java SE 8 IntStream.reduce(..) (etc) seems to be operating inconsistently

Tags: java-8

I'm looking at various aspects of Java SE 8. I've encountered a number of situations where compilable code leads to runtime exceptions or apparent inconsistencies. Here is one, where a construct operates as expected in one context, but appears to fail in another. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Stream06 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce((i,j)->i+j).getAsInt());        // OK
        out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce(0,(i,j)->i+j));                 // OK
        out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce((i,j)->i*j).getAsInt());        // OK!
        out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce(0,(i,j)->i*j));                 // zero!!!

        out.println();
        out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce((l,m)->l+m).getAsLong());       // OK
        out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce(0,(l,m)->l+m));                 // OK
        out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce((l,m)->l*m).getAsLong());       // OK!
        out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(2,5)
            .reduce(0,(l,m)->l*m));                 // zero!!!

        out.println();
        out.println(DoubleStream.of(2.5, 1.3, 6.8)
            .reduce((d,e)->d+e).getAsDouble());     // OK
        out.println(DoubleStream.of(2.5, 1.3, 6.8)
            .reduce(0,(d,e)->d+e));                 // OK
        out.println(DoubleStream.of(2.5, 1.3, 6.8)
            .reduce((d,e)->d*e).getAsDouble());     // OK (usual rounding issue)
        out.println(DoubleStream.of(2.5, 1.3, 6.8)
            .reduce(0,(d,e)->d*e));                 // zero!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: [doc for `IntStream.reduce`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-): *The `identity` value must be an identity for the accumulator function* Did you read and understand that sentence? The identity for multiplication is `1` not `0`.

Comment: @user3627702 What runtime exceptions have you encountered? Regarding getting a zero result, others have pointed out that's expected if you use zero as the "identity" value for reduction over multiplication. If you don't understand this, maybe you should recast the question in those terms. I think that would be a relevant, on-topic question.

Comment: Runtime exceptions were using .from(TemporalAccessor) in more than one context eg ZonedDateTime.from(anInstant) which my reading of the documentation says should work.

Comment: As regards the identity issue over multiplication, using 1 as the identity of course solves the problem for a non-empty stream, but 1 is almost certainly an inappropriate return value for an empty stream. Therefore the single parameter version of reduce would seem to be more appropriate, accessing the returned OptionalInt with .orElse(0). It would be useful if there were further examples and discussion of issues like this either in the tutorials or, preferably, in the API documentation for the individual method.

Answer (score 3):

reduce `i*j` starting from zero leads to zero... well, that's quite expected :-)